# remove alpahabets from string by function

Tags: mysql

remove alpahabets from string by function in sql

```
id     Kms
1      100 kms
2      200 kms
3      50 kms
7      43 kms
```

How to remove the kms from the Kms field using a function ?

Comment: There are many string functions, you may use some of them - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "replace" function in MySQL for that:

```
replace(FIELD_NAME, ‘find this string’, ‘replace found string with this string’)
```

so that would be:

```
replace(FIELD_NAME, ‘kms’, ‘’)
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL automatically converts strings to numbers by discarding non-numeric suffixes. You can write for example:

```
SELECT 0+kms FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

As Joni mentioned, MySQL will type-juggle strings with numeric values when treated numerical. For instance, on your table, the query:

```
SELECT SUM(Kms) FROM yourTable;
```

Will return : `393`

I made a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/927b4/1) that shows it as well.